# Tensor-flow Warnings for GPU Computation

Tags: tensorflow

When I was running Hello Tensor-flow program on Google Cloud Instances, I have warnings below:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:04.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.09GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x27b1fe0


I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 2
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 2
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 3
  tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 2
```

I think the GPUs are actually giving me results but I am not sure if I need to fix those warnings.

FYI, I also encountered the warnings for SSE3/SSE4.1/SSE4.2/AVX/AVX2/FMA compiling. But since I mainly work on GPU computation, I put them at lower priority.

Comment: Those are not warnings, "I " prefix means they are Information messages ("W " would mean warning), you can safely ignore them. It's telling you that there's no DMA access between GPUs so don't rely on that. For instance, when using multi-gpus, put your parameters on /cpu:0 rather than /gpu:0

Comment: Thank you Bulatov! So as you mentioned DMA access between GPUs, since I would work on multi-gpus, what did you mean by "put your parameters on /cpu:0 rather than /gpu:0"? Am I supposed to do any configurations to leverage multi-gpus resources?

Comment: yes, tensorflow doesn't use more than one gpu by default, you have to assign your ops to specific gpus, see cifar multi-gpu example